# iOS RSSFeed, How to fech feed automatic from website

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, rss

I am working on news based application in which I want to fetch the dynamic feed with just typing website's name.

**For example:** If i want to fetch feed from CNN.com or BBCNEWS.com or etc  , then i have to just write website name in textbox  like "BBC.com" in place of it's rss urlname

http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml.

*I know how to fetch  feed from static link but i want to do it dynamically*

I have searched a lot regarding this but havn't find any answer. I have seen this in [**feedly**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feedly-your-work-newsfeed/id396069556?mt=8) application. In which they have done like this.

so, if anybody know then help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS comes with a mechanism call [Auto-Discovery](http://blog.superfeedr.com/rss-autodiscovery/) which links RSS feeds to an HTML page.

It relies on the use of a `<link>` element in the `<head>` section of any HTML page.

> The `<link>` tag includes 4 important elements:
>
> - `rel` should include alternate which tells the application that the linked document contains an alternate view of the current
>     document/page. You can also use the feed value, even though, in our
>     experience, this is much less frequent. Using both is probably a safe
>     bet
> - `type` indicates the MIME type of this alternate representation. RSS uses application/rss+xml while Atom uses application/atom+xml
> - `title` is a human description of the document. It’s good to re-use the page’s title. Do not add RSS as it’s meaningless for people :)
> - `href` is the most important attribute: it’s the URL (relative or absolute) of the feed.

Here’s, for example, the discovery for this page's very RSS feed:

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question &#39;iOS RSSFeed, How to fech feed automatic from website&#39;" href="/feeds/question/32946522">`

It's a great example!

Comment: thanks a lot for help. I have used your way but to find link i have used nsscanner class and i am stuck at regex (character-set)format. if you have any idea can you please help me in this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007842/ios-how-to-find-full-rss-feed-link-with-nsscanner-class

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML of the site, you'll find a snippet like this

`<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='RSS' href='http://feeds.feedburner.com/martini'>`

That's where the RSS URL comes from.

Comment: how to implement it in ios ?